# Declaring enum in a header, invisible in source file?

Tags: c, dll, enums, header, shared-libraries

In the source file (which is from a shared object / DLL), I get `OKAY could not be resolved`, although it is in the header. The header is in another project but I dont think that should be related, as ppackage is resolved properly ?

**Update, here the source:**

- foor.c a/k/a source: https://github.com/linuxrocksrulers/m5/blob/ec4f62ba1c/foor/src/foor.c#L19
- m5.h a/k/a header: https://github.com/linuxrocksrulers/m5/blob/ec4f62ba1c/m5/src/include/m5.h#L34

Build output from building foor project.

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/foor.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -I"/home/lk/proj/m5/m5/src/include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF"src/foor.d" -MT"src/foor.d" -o "src/foor.o" "../src/foor.c"
In file included from ../src/foor.c:9:0:
/home/lk/proj/m5/m5/src/include/m5.h:33:3: warning: #warning ohshit
../src/foor.c:12:1: warning: missing braces around initializer
../src/foor.c:12:1: warning: (near initialization for 'fs[1]')
Finished building: ../src/foor.c

Building target: libfoor.so
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -shared -o "libfoor.so"  ./src/foor.o   
Finished building target: libfoor.so
```

header:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum {
    OKAY = 0,
    ERR,
    ERRANY,
    // list shortened
    ERRNOTFOUND,
};

typedef struct { ..foobars.. } ppackage;
```

source file:

```
#include <header.h> // Did add -I ../include, where the header is

ppackage knock(ppackage *in)
{
    return OKAY; // ERROR
}
```

Comment: You should use `#include ""` instead of `#include <>` for your own header files and keep `<>` for the system files

Comment: Then i would have to create links and that is very unportable and even dirtier, as i have many projects. But yes it should be. Except that this is cross-project header. Weirdly the main program, which is no shared library/DLL, works(can use `OKAY` and everything), opposed to the source file shown here which can only use structs....

Comment: according to the directory structure you uploaded to github, you should use `-I include` not `-I ../include`, since the source file is in the same directory as the `include` directory.

Comment: @ChrisBrowne I simplified it. ppackage is still usable in foor and I dont get an error on the header. The actual include is correct. But I still dont understand this.

Comment: I don't see the error in your compiler output.  All I see is a warning that you told the compiler to produce on a certain line.  There is nothing there about the macro OKAY.

Comment: @ChrisBrowne OH! I just looked at the nicely tabularized error list which eclipse produced, there the error is listed. In the build log it is missing. I even just now noticed the libfoor.so was indeed there. This must be an eclipse related issue. Anyone knows a way to entirely re-parse the entire workspace?

Comment: Use the Project menu to re-build the project.  There's a reason I don't use eclipse for C/C++ by the way...

Comment: @ChrisBrowne Re-build is working, but the error does not go away. Why do you not use Eclipse ? What else do you use (except from MS Visual C++). Id appreciate a long response-comment from you =).

Comment: I don't use Eclipse for C/C++ because it's primarily designed for Java, and it's great for Java, but I have no end of troubles getting it to work with Makefiles.  The most heavyweight IDE I've ever used for C/C++ work is Geany, and I very often just use Vi.  That said, I rarely do any 'serious' work in C/C++, so I don't think I'm the best person to ask about C/C++ IDEs.

Comment: @imacake What do you mean you would have to create links ? no way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include the header, then all the code in that header could just as well have been pasted into your C source file at the point where the `#include` directive is.

It sounds strange that it isn't working.

One thing to do would be to use quotes rather than angle brackets for the include, since you're including a 3rd-party header.

Also, please include exact compiler output.

Comment: I guess that is detail enough =D ?

Comment: Since you're using GCC, try running just the C Preprocessor: instead of "-c", use "-E -P" and redirect the output to "foor.i". (The "-P" option takes out the line number directives.)  Now simply compile: "gcc -c foor.i".  This will give you the line number in "foor.i" where the error is occurring and you can look at the fully preprocessed code to see what the problem is.

Comment: @AlexMeasday Why isnt there a "Favourite comment" button... Thanks insanely!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear, that your enum is related to ..foobars..

Ppackage knock(ppackage *in) should have a return value of type ppackage, which is a struct { ..foobars..}

Does

```
   typedef enum {
    OKAY = 0,
    ERR,
    ERRANY,
    // list shortened
    ERRNOTFOUND,
   } preturnvalue_t;
```

with a function

```
   preturnvalue_t knock(ppackage *in)
   { 
      return OKAY; // ERROR
   }
```

do what you need?

Lutz